# Node.js Websocket Socket.io Steam MongoDB not saving data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, websocket, socket.io, steam

I have website hosting at GoDaddy.
I have VPS at DigitalOcean.

Im going to my website (At GoDaddy hosting) and have an input field (Lets name it trade-link field, because it should contain URL).

User puts URL in "trade-link" field > press "Save" button > data is being sent through Websocket to VPS (At DigitalOcean) > Data is being saved in MongoDB.

The last step is not working.
I have a little code which logs whats got on console:

```
{"type":1,"steamid":"76561198092387621","link":"steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/new/?partner=THISISURL";}
```

So data is being received by server, its okey. Now there is are problem. This data needs to be saved to MongoDB.

---

Lets start to input field at my website (GoDaddy):

```
<input type="text" rel="get-trade-link" id="par2" name="par2" placeholder="https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/new/?partner=URL">
                        <div class="btn-yellow save-link">
```

And then script.js file (Godaddy):

```
var socket = io.connect('http://url:8303');
ws = new WebSocket('ws://url:8305');

    function sendTradeLink(tradelink){
        ws.send(JSON.stringify({
            type: 1,
            steamid: getSteamID(),
            link: tradelink
        }));
    }

$(document).on('click', '.save-link', function() {
        var link = $('input[rel="get-trade-link"]').val();
        if (link.indexOf('https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/new/?partner=') < 0) {
        } else {
            sendTradeLink(link);
                }
        }   
    });
```

VPS:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8303);


// all another
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
var wss = new WebSocketServer({ port: 8305 });

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    console.log('received: %s', message);
  });

  ws.send('something');
});

socket.on('1', function(data){
    updateTradeLink(data.steamid, data.link);
});
```

'1' - I think it means 'type'. Its not my script, I bought it, but its very hard to communicate with him.

```
    socket.on('link', function(data){
        userListDB.find({'steamid':data.steamId, 'type' : 'link'}).toArray(function(err, list) { 
            socket.emit('link', { list : list });
        });
    });   

 function updateTradeLink(sid, link) {
        if(!g_Mongoconnected)
            return 0;

        existUser(sid, function(exist){
            if(exist) {
                userListDB.update({steamid: sid}, {steamid: sid, tradelink: link, type : 'link'});
            } else {
                userListDB.insert({steamid: sid, tradelink: link, type : 'link'}, {w:1}, function(err) {
                    if(err) {
                        helper.log('Error inserting tradelink', 485, err);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

P.S I bought that script and added that part of the code by myself:

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
var wss = new WebSocketServer({ port: 8305 });

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    console.log('received: %s', message);
  });

  ws.send('something');
});
```

EDIT:

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017', function (err, db) {
    if (err) {
        helper.log('Mongodb connection error', 425, err); 
        return 0;
    }

    userListDB = db.collection('users');
    gameDB = db.collection('gamedb');
    g_Mongoconnected = true;
    helper.msg('mongo connected');

    gameDB.find({name: 'counter'}).toArray(function (error, list) {
        if(list.length == 0) {
            currentGame=0; 
            gameDB.insert({name: 'counter', counter: 0}, {w:1}, function(err) {if(err) console.log('Error <1>');});
        } else {
            currentGame = list[0].counter;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Rather than take a snapshot of your code, paste the code right into your question.  Use { } icon on top to add markdown coding.  Makes it much easier for folks to help you.

Comment: Well I'm certainly lost.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish? What is not working the way you expect it to? What is a trade URL (I'll trade you one Yahoo for Two Googles?)  Why are you using sockets in the first place? Is sockets the best way to do that?  Where is server hosted at?  Do they support Node.js with sockets?   (etc...)

Comment: Its a CS:GO related website. You need to set your trade url: like steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/new/?partner=something etc. 1. You go to website and set your trade URL. 2. I get that url through Websocket connection to server. 3. Its need to be saved to MongoDB, but its not. Like you can see, Im getting these URLs, but its not saving to MongoDB

Comment: "Somebody Puts a Link in My Website"  huh? Is that a server you are hosting, or is that a website of your creation, hosted at steamcommunity?  If its your hosting, why bother with sockets? Take the data from a submit at your site and stick it into Mongo.  If at Steamcommunity, how do you know they even allow socket connections?  Most servers don't.

Comment: I host website at Godaddy hosting, its allowed. I bought the script, need to configure it, the guy who sold me that is speaking different language and its hard to understand what hes saying.

Comment: Its like My website input form ( field to input trade-link) (Godaddy hosting) > user press button > Websocket > VPS At DigitalOcean. Server gets responses from the website, but it looks like that even functions to input "trade-link" to MongoDB not even start working. And thats the problem.

Comment: Huh? You have a VPS at DigitalOcean?  Why isn't your entire website there? At any rate, So your client app creates a socket and sends a message to the server at digital ocean.  If you send generic text messages from the client application, can you read the text messages at the node server at digital ocean (hint, `console.log()` is your friend...)  Break this down into little pieces.. Good communication via socket?  Save data into MongoDB?

Comment: Because its kinda slow (tried mysql, really slow) + I got domain + hosting for 1 year very cheap. Yes, user press save and console show this:

Comment: `...show this:` ??  Missing something.  Best is to edit your question above...  And VPS at DigitalOcean not as fast as shared hosting at GoDaddy?  Something is definitely wrong there.  It should be much faster...

Comment: Because its kinda slow (tried mysql, really slow) + I got domain + hosting for 1 year very cheap. Yes, user press save and console show this: received: {"type":1,"steamid":"76561198092387622","link":"https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/new/?partner=THISISURL"}
but function " socket.on('1', function(data){
  updateTradeLink(data.steamid, data.link);
 });" is not working

Comment: Yes, ill try to change my question.

Comment: Ah... change `socket.on('1',...` to `ws.on(`...

Comment: Ill try this, but I tried it some time ago, but let see...

Answer (score 0):

Try this modification:

```
wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
    ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
        console.log('received: %s', message);
        if(message.type == 1){
            updateTradeLink(message.steamid, message.link);
        };
        if(message.type =='link'){
            userListDB.find({'steamid':message.steamId, 'type' : 'link'}).toArray(function(err, list) { 
                ws.emit('link', { list : list });
            }
        };
    });
});
```

and then onto the Mongo DB stuff:

```
function updateTradeLink(sid, link) {
    if(!g_Mongoconnected){
        console.log('Oops. Mongo DB not connected..');
        return 0;
    }

    existUser(sid, function(exist){
        if(exist) {
            userListDB.update({steamid: sid}, {steamid: sid, tradelink: link, type : 'link'});
        } else {
            userListDB.insert({steamid: sid, tradelink: link, type : 'link'}, {w:1}, function(err) {
                if(err) {
                    helper.log('Error inserting tradelink', 485, err);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried this:  wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
 ws.on('1', function(data){
  updateTradeLink(data.steamid, data.link);
 });
});

Comment: Now at least Im getting error: userListDB.find({'steamid':data.steamId, 'type' : 'link'}).toArray(function( ^ ReferenceError: data is not defined

Comment: So that means we've got the socket communication thing down pat.  The problem now is with the MongoDB stuff.  Let me do say, I'm way impressed with your updates, code clean up, and much better communications.  Unfortunately, I'd like to see all the MongoDB setup code...particularly where is userListDB defined?  Where is existUser defined? also g_Mongoconnected

Comment: var userListDB, gcDB, gameDB;

Comment: function existUser (user, callback) {
 if(!g_Mongoconnected)
  return 0;

 userListDB.find({steamid: user}).toArray(function (error, list) {
  callback (list.length !== 0);
 });
}

Comment: userListDB = db.collection('users');
 gameDB = db.collection('gamedb');

Comment: But isnt the problem now is data.steamId? The "data" is not defined, something bad is with that, not MongoDB?

Comment: Fixed this, now it wont crash. But still, data is not being saved.

Comment: er.. you shouldn't have the word `data` in your node server.js code at all.  I've essentially replaced it with `message` but that is only defined within a very small scope within your program.  See my edits to the code in my answer.

Comment: Could you update the original question to show the code surrounding the mongoDB connection (please ensure you do NOT paste in real address or authentication keys)?  Is there any test in there to ensure the connection to mongoDB is working?

Comment: I edited post. Please look at "Edit" (Bottom) code. I dont know how to use MongoDB, but it looks like its using db.collection but what "db" it use? I searched all document, havent found what is db. Question is, it is even conected to database?

Comment: Hm, I tried: mongodb://localhost:27017/database, it connects to it. I tried to see what collections are made in that "database" in mongo console, and it shows: [ "gamedb", "system.indexes" ]
Question is, where is "userListDB = db.collection('users');"? And what is "system_indexes). And maybe there is that problem.